# Параметризованный запрос в WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

Доброго времени суток!
Возникла проблема, узнал, что если команда к SQL-серверу собрана из данных введенных пользователем, то такой запрос является опасным, поэтому необходимо создать параметризованный запрос, НО как это сделать в цикле что-то не могу понять.
Вот как реализовал я с помощью конкатенации:

```
string query = "SELECT row1, row2, row3 FROM Opr where 1";
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.Text != "")
            {
                query += "and " + c.Name + " = " + "'" + c.Text + "' ";
                query = query.Replace("_text", "");
                query = query.Replace("1and", "");                                 
            }                   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qwertiy, я правильно Вас понял?

```
string query = "SELECT row1, row2, row3 FROM Opr where ";
        SSqlCommand commandTest = new SqlCommand();
        SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query);
        IEnumerable<Control> TextB = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(text => text.Text!="");
        foreach (Control c in TextB)
        {
            c.Name = c.Name.Replace("_text","");
            sb.Append(c.Name + "=@" + c.Name+" and ");
            Param = new SqlParameter("@"+c.Name, c.Text);
            commandSearch.Parameters.Add(Param);                                                 
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 4);
        commandSearch.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        commandSearch.Connection = connect;
```

Но мне по прежнему выдает "предупреждение" с кодом [CA2100](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182310.aspx), хотя c.Name - это имя объекта, а не его экземпляр и как я полагаю пользователь-злоумышленник не может повлиять на имя textbox, указанное для идентификации объекта.

Comment: Кроме того, что в коде какая-то жесть творится, на правду вполне похоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так лучше?

Comment: @Tibomso используйте Controls.OfType<TextBox>() - это уберет ручную проверку на тип

Comment: @Tibomso  CA2100 это общее предупреждение. оно выстреливает на любую попытку собрать SQL динамически. Если вы проревьювили код, убедились что в *тексте* запроса нет строк вводимых пользователем (а у вас их тепер нет) - то можно спокойно делать suppress. Это прямо сказано в справке по предупреждению- It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule if the command text does not contain any user input.

Comment: @PashaPash, это круто! Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1):

Один из подходов решения проблемы SQL Injection через параметризацию - это оборачивание своих запросов в хранимые процедуры. Весь тот же код, который сейчас используете, заключаете в хранимую процедуру, определяете ее параметры, при вызове процедуры переданные параметры добавляете в запрос.

В коде вам достаточно вызвать процедуру, передав в качестве параметров нужные значения.

Еще одно положительное свойство работы через хранимые процедуры - это ограничение прав - вы можете дать учетке, от имени которой работает ваше приложение, права только за запуск процедуры, не добавляя прав на прямой доступ к таблицам и снижая вероятность несанкционированного удаления или изменения данных.

Comment: Не очень-то связано с вопросом...

Comment: Напрямую связано - это способ делать параметризованный вызов для избавления от SQL Injection. Ваш ответ вот легко позволяет SQL Injection провести, так что с вопросом связано, но ответом не является.

Comment: Где он позволяет sql injection? o_O

Comment: Там, где значение передается в параметр - я этого кода даже не вижу у вас в ответе, и какую его реализацию вы предполагаете - я не знаю. Можно сделать неправильную.

Comment: Но я же подставляю имя параметра - как можно потом передать параметры так, чтобы получиласт sql-инъекция? Предполагается new SqlParameter со строковым типом для всех полей.

Comment: Зачем предполагать, если можно сразу написать об этом? Добавить тот самый new SqlParameter в пример кода и заполнение его значением - кстати, правильный комментарий к вашему ответу о том, что неплохо бы сразу знать тип переменных и передавать их - приведение строк не всегда делается корректно.

Comment: Мой ответ основан на том, что код автора работает - а там-то строки. Ну и поля все текстовые - для других типов логично использовать несколько другие поля ввода.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> query += "and " + c.Name + " = " + "'" + c.Text + "' ";
> ```

```
query += "and " + c.Name + " = @" + c.Name + " ";
```

Сюда же создание параметра.

> ```
> string query
> ```

Используй `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Вроде, при параметеризации нужно указывать тип переменных=> если условие строится динамически, то и типы откуда-то нужно брать. Например, лезть в схему таблицы...

Comment: @iluxa1810, всё в строки, а sql-сервер сам скастит? Исходный код-то работал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: То есть вы считаете, что создание запроса конкатенацией не подвержено SQL injection?

Comment: @Alex78191, в конкатенации используются имена контролов формы, а не пользовательские данные. Ну уж если ты сам текстбокс назвал так, что там sql injection внутри, то что тут скажешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy `Control.Text` может вводится пользователем.

Comment: @Alex78191, где в **моём** коде `Control.Text` в конкатенации? Он есть в цитате из вопроса, а у меня он заменён на именованный параметр.

Comment: Прошу прощения.